# Plot a Line Graph

Tags: excel, linegraph

There is a scenario where I have to create a line graph in excel or anywhere which represents two approaches. The parameters involved are:

1. The number of systems on which both old and new approach is tested.
2. The number of calls made on each system.
3. Amount of time taken for each call.

Can you please help me how do I represent this in tabular format so that I can create a line graph with one axis as time taken and other one as System/Calls made:

```
System1
============================

Call 1:
--------------
Old Approach:
That took 15.658 seconds.

New Approach:
That took 8.076 seconds.

Call 2:
--------------
Old Approach:
That took 10.054 seconds.

New Approach:
That took 5.65 seconds.


System2
============================

Call 1:
--------------
Old Approach:
That took 13.775 seconds.

New Approach:
That took 4.542 seconds.

Call 2:
--------------
Old Approach:
That took 10.097 seconds.

New Approach:
That took 4.0200000000000005 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually want a bar chart if you want to see the time difference between old and new approaches under each system (using the axes layout you describe).

I will leave images of both so you can see what i mean. From a data layout point of you, it is often best to create a flat table where each column is a distinct attribute and of the same datatype. I.e. there are not mixed datatypes or different measures within the same column. I would recommend reading parts of chapter 2, as a minimum, of Hadley Wickam's paper on [Tidy Data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). You don't need to understand the R language to get a lot out of chapter 2.

If you have multiple repeated measurements you could plot the average rather than the sum, or even better would be the median as less prone to skew i.e. less biased by a very long or short call present in the data set.

[image: Image of different chart types and data layout]

Comment: Awesome, Thanks exactly what I wanted. One more thing, can you share this excel with me?

Comment: How about give it a go first, see how far you get and message back if struggling? You need to lay your data out as in image top left, then whilst inside the data range, go to charts tab of ribbon > pivotchart > select the little down arrow then PivotChart & PivotTable. You can see the fields layout to the right above each of the charts.

Comment: Sure, I will follow the steps. Will ask here if I struggle.Thanks!